# How to open a window in current space using Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, mission-control

Let's say I have Evernote open in space 2 and while in space 1, I would like to click in the dock or switch (using keyboard) to evernote and have it (evernote) open in space 1. Any idea?

Previously I could do it by just pressing CMD before clicking the icon. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Control click on the Evernote icon in the dock and navigate into options. You can then change Evernote to belong to the current desktop or All desktops which should bring about the change of having the Evernote app present in your current desktop.